# Visual Studio Code keeps Autosizing my Text Lines

Tags: visual-studio-code

Visual Studio Code keeps scrunching and separating my code in the right window into multiple lines, if the left pane is too wide. It used to never be like that.  How can I change this setting, so VS Code does not auto window size the right panel?

[image]

Comment: The option I think you're looking for is 'word wrap' under the View menu, or with the shortcut, Alt-Z.

Comment: @WillWalsh feel free to write in answer, and I can send points, thanks, also, can you upvote my question?